# Django: Unexpected keyword error when trying to create with correct parameters

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm just starting out in Django and following along with a tutorial. I've copied exactly what they did, but I'm still getting this unexplained error.

For this particular app, my very simple models.py file looks like this:

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField
    description = models.TextField
    price = models.TextField
    summary = models.TextField(default='This is cool!')
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code, but when I use the Python shell and write `Product.objects.create(title="test", description = "test2", price = "test3", summary = "test4")`, it throws the error `TypeError: Product() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'`. What am I missing? Is there a deeper problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use it like this: `models.TextField()`

Comment: Yeah, I realized a few minutes after I posted, this is what I get for coding late at night. Thanks!